# Discord JS command for selected people

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a Discord bot for one server. I want to create a command that will work only if the author of the message has an ID that is included in an allowed list of IDs.

I tried it like this:

```
const allowedusers = [
  "ID",
  "ID",
  "ID",
]

if (msg.author.id !== allowedusers) {
  //code for not allowed users
}
else {
  //code for allowed users
}
```

This code doesn't work. I want it to work so that it gives the ID of a person who can do so, and by entering the command, the bot responds. However, if the ID is not allowed, the bot responds: ERROR.

I hope someone will help me. I would like to add that when I give one ID, everything works fine.

Comment: You can't compare an Array of strings and a string directly, quite like you can't directly compare apples and oranges. Use `Array.prototype.includes()` to discern if the array you've declared here contains the author's message ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the author's ID is in the list:

```
const allowedusers = [
  "ID1",
  "ID2",
  "ID3",
]

if (allowedusers.includes(msg.author.id)) {
  //code for allowed users
} else {
  //code for not allowed users
}
```